# Push notifications not sending with test despite having APN & specific device FCM token

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've looked all over stackoverflow and google for an answer to this, these are some of the things I've tried:

- Following Google's [Client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#objective-c) and [Receive](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) Guides.
- Made sure firebase has proper APN settings.
- [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63581953/5501040).
- [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983625/5501040).

I'll run through what I've got:

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@import Firebase;
@import UserNotifications;

/** Flipper **/
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  #import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
  #import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
  #import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
  #import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
  #import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
  #import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

  static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
    FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
    SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
    [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
    [client start];
  }
#endif
/** End Flipper **/

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above.
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
    InitializeFlipper(application);
  #endif

  [FIRApp configure];

  [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;

  /* Messaging */
  if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
    // iOS 10 or later
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
        UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
        requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
        completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          // ...
        }];
  } else {
    // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }

  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

  /*
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] tokenWithCompletion:^(NSString *token, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Error getting FCM registration token: %@", error);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", token);
      //[FIRMessaging messaging].fcmRegTokenMessage.text = token;
    }
  }];
  /* End Messaging */

  /* Bridge */
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"UBFounders"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  /* End Bridge */

  return YES;
}

/* Monitor token refresh */
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    // Notify about received token.
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
/* End token refresh */

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // [START_EXCLUDE]
  // Print message ID.
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }
  // [END_EXCLUDE]

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // [START_EXCLUDE]
  // Print message ID.
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }
  // [END_EXCLUDE]

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  // Change this to your preferred presentation option
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  completionHandler();
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  #endif
}

@end
```

So basically I run the app, fetch the FCM Registration Token from the Console, as so:
[image]

Then I add the token to the Notification Center and try a test send, as so:
[image]

You can see from the reports, none of the notifications are being received, as so:
[image]

Not sure what else to try. Thoughts?

---

EDIT: Update to reflect relevant javascript:

index.js

```
import messaging, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {});
```

App.js

```
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";

// Push notifications function
async function push_notifications_setup() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  // Check if we have permissions
  if (authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL) {
    messaging().subscribeToTopic("podcasts");
  }
}

export default function App() {
  // TODO: Uncomment for push notifications 
  // Request push notification permissions
  push_notifications_setup();

  ...
}
```

Comment: What package are you using? react-native-push-notification or react-native-firebase? Did you implement the javascript code? Without it, it won't work

Comment: @FrancescoClementi I added the JS, but I don't think that's relevant when using the firebase console.

Comment: You have one or more delegate methods missing.  Where is `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`?

Comment: Moreover, where are you getting the token? I couldn't receive notification whenn I was getting the token with react-native-push-notification which weren't FCM token

Comment: @ElTomato I didn't find any delegate method of that name in any tutorial I found, what code should I be inserting?

@FrancescoClementi I'm getting the FCM token from the console. It's being outputted from the `didReceiveRegistrationToken` method.

Comment: Ok @FrancescoClementi and @ElTomato I seemed to figure something out. I got it to work by adding [this code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/87affc1bd0b5f7090d987dbb925ec646665f1235/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m#L172-L180) to `AppDelegate.m` but with line 179 uncommented. But what is this swizzling and what do I need to do to make this work on production?